# Exporting Context not working with contextType

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file `App.js`, from which a React component is exported as default. Besides that, the same file exports a React Context.

When using the Context in a child component (using `static contextType = Context`), I just get the following warning:

```
Warning: Versions defines an invalid contextType. contextType should point to the Context object returned by React.createContext(). However, it is set to undefined. This can be caused by a typo or by mixing up named and default imports. This can also happen due to a circular dependency, so try moving the createContext() call to a separate file.
```

`this.context` is also undefined.

However, using the consumer in the render method works just fine:

```
<Context.Consumer>{({ name }) => <p>{name}</p>}</Context.Consumer>
```

To better understand the issue, here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-wood-qzrk1?fontsize=14 (see the console for the warning).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you have a cyclic dependency here between App.js and the child component `version.js`

To solve the problem, all you need to do is to move context creation into a separate file

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cdn-19mj5)

Comment: Can you explain cyclic dependency for me ?

Comment: Usually a cyclic dependency means that `A` depends on `B` that depends on `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-kilby-uoeso)

For the context I have created a single file 'MilestoneContext.js'. Exported the context from here and imported this context to both places `App.js` and `Versions.js`.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This gets rid of the warning, but I still need to access `this.context` in some methods inside the component. In this case it would just be undefined.